Is it possible to convert a USB Legacy charger to support USB-C Power delivery with an active adapter in between
I have noticed a lot of new USB-C devices don't make use of the full potential of legacy USB A chargers, when adapting from USB A to USB-C with just a regular cable. For example using a 5V 2.4 Amp charger on newer devices  made for PD charging like iPad Pro/s, iPhone's, Android phones tend top out at or just under 7 Watts maximum on the old chargers? Which seems like a waste of the full potential on the old chargers. I am guessing this is a limit on the device being charged and what power it can pull from old non-power delivery chargers, is this the case? Can't seem to find any solid info, but ya this is in practice from using in line usb voltage meter.
The idea proposed is a board that connects to the old USB A charger brick and can pull the full 5V 2.4 amp legacy standard. And then add in a bridge board that takes the 5V 2.4 A input and implements a 5V USB-C output with power delivery implemented with supported power range of 5V 0.1A to 2.4A This would allow you to get closer to a 12 Watt charger Max instead of capping out at 7 Watt and should charge a lot faster using the same old adapter and not need a whole new usb-c power delivery charger purchase. Does this seem workable or reasonable seems no one has made anything like this yet that I have found? What am I missing?

they are power supplies, not chargers ... the battery charger is built into the device that contains the battery

It's difficult to say what exactly is going on without having the devices in hand (and possibly some reverse engineering too)... but ~7W (~1.4A) is already way above what USB-A "should" technically provide, so it's quite possible that these devices are attempting to balance the current vs voltage drop (due to over-current and across the cable - more technically the supply voltage as measured by themselves). If so, then a better cable is a much cheaper and more technically elegant route! Have you tried it? PD may not actually help here...

I have tried several cables including ones from Anker rated for 5V 3A, all perform the same with this seemingly artificial, limit it does not matter the Cable but the device itself, in the cases I have tried. For example my Type S battery back can pull up to 5V 2A as rated on itself, not sure if its using PD or just regular USB charging it has a micro usb next to it with same input rating so probably legacy charging on both???

Try the experiment on any smart mobile device android or iOS with a usb-C port, never see them pull more than ~7 Watts when going from usb A to USB-C without a power delivery charger

@MrDaniel That's because it uses QC or something similar. Literally nobody implemented PD on Type-A connector and even if someone did, your phone likely would not know how to communicate PD over VBUS with Type-A supply. My phone uses QC instead of PD with the QC charger and can pull 15W, over standard Type-A to Type-C cable. So YMMV.

@Attie There are standards-compliant ways to provide higher current (up to 1.5 A I believe) on a USB-A connector. Look up the USB battery charging specification for more information. This predates USB-PD, and just provides more current at the same 5 V.

@Hearth - indeed / apologies, I was taking the most basic viewpoint and should have clarified.

This is of course possible, but you'll end up with a device that costs as much as a dedicated USB 3 charger if it sells in the same volume. Since it will sell way less, it won't benefit from the massive benefits of scale so it will be more expensive than a dedicated charger.
Furthermore you end up having a devices that's useless on its own and marginally more useful than a USB 2 charger when combined, while if you buy a new charger you now have two fully functional chargers.

and not need a whole new usb-c power delivery charger

Your hypothetical gadget must contain almost everything that a stand-alone charger does so it is essentially a whole new usb-c power delivery charger except it runs on 5 volts input.

Sure it is possible, but the question is really why it should be done even if possible.
Not all adapters can give you 2.4A. There is no standard (except proprietary standards which are proprietary such as Apple products) that allows you to detect if your middleman adapter can even draw 2.4A from the source.
The USB BC 1.2 standard goes up to 5V 1.5A or 7.5W and it is a real standard used by everyone. Type-C standard also allows up to 1.5A or 7.5W at 5V, even without PD - it will also go up to 3A but of course that can't be advertized if your supply is 2.4A.
The list of standards doesn't even end there - the ten year old QC 2.0 standard can provide 18W or 9V at 2A. You just need to communicate that too and then convert the voltage down to 5V so you could even charge at 5V 3A without PD.
So as there are already so many standards, it would move the problem of not having enough power or being able to detect how much power there is from the phone to your device.
It will just make much more sense to buy a Type-C PD charger if your devices support it, rather than still dealing with the problem of which USB adapters you can use to convert to Type-C and to which voltages - e.g. a 45W charger can output 3A at 15W but it can alsp output 20V but up to 2.25A so that your devices can request the best possible voltage for best possible charging (either max current in minimum charging time, or most efficiency for least waste of energy as heat).
It might even be that the phone or whatever will complain about 5V no matter how much current is available, if it would really rather use 9V or 12V for charging.
So anyway while converting voltage up or down from power supply to target device is possible, energy would be lost a bit in the voltage conversion process, and there will be less available.
Also if you keep 5V from supply to device, all the connectors and cables are going to add some resistance, which means the voltage at the end.of cable could be out of valid specs unless it is anyway boosted back to valid range.
Just simpler for people to find out they have a supply and device with matching connectors and it just works when plugged in.
